# How can I assign a port to VM without ip in openstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I get following error when I create a port with --no-fixied-ip option and assign to a VM.

Port c0636994-e926-464f-b47d-00d83098d39c requires a FixedIP in order to be used. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-76e44907-1dad-407a-b922-49230054986a)

Is it allowed operation in openstack?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which openstack release are you using? In Victoria this works as expected for me:

```
root@control01:~# openstack port create --no-fixed-ip --network 48cf59e4-cee6-424d-8003-94bcc0913926 test-port

root@control01:~# openstack port show 481adfb6-8f9a-452a-8056-a8a0d2cb6db1 -c fixed_ips -f value
[]

root@control01:~# nova interface-attach --port-id 481adfb6-8f9a-452a-8056-a8a0d2cb6db1 c17125f3-9bbd-49a9-9922-4b56a4767625
+------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property   | Value                                |
+------------+--------------------------------------+
| ip_address |                                      |
| mac_addr   | fa:16:3e:b8:72:44                    |
| net_id     | 48cf59e4-cee6-424d-8003-94bcc0913926 |
| port_id    | 481adfb6-8f9a-452a-8056-a8a0d2cb6db1 |
| port_state | DOWN                                 |
| tag        | -                                    |
+------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: im using train release and this error pops up, when I use the openstack server create with  --port <> option.

Comment: Do you have the `ip_allocation` extension enabled? You can check with `openstack extension list | grep allocation`. There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1741575), maybe you're hit by that. Also, Train is EOL for quite some time now, have you considered upgrading?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
`
# openstack extension list | grep allocation
Extensions list not supported by Identity API
| Subnet Allocation                                                                                                                                              | subnet_allocation                     | Enables allocation of subnets from a subnet pool                                                                                                         # 
`

I dont see ip_allocation available. Any help on that?
Upgrade to latest version is gonna take time.

Comment: I think it can be enabled by adding "segments" to `service_plugins` in neutron.conf: `grep service_plugins /etc/neutron/neutron.conf
service_plugins = router,segments`